# How can I conditionally close a tag using Angular.js?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

How can I conditionally close a tag using Angular.js?  For example, in the attached plunk, how would I close the fluid-row div and create a new div after every fifth item so that only five items appear per row.

http://plnkr.co/edit/WFC9Jmm6afT2Za7TKiMj?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

Conditionally closing a tag is not really possible with ng-repeat.
Two ways for solving your problem:

- A directive, requires a bit more work, but you can conditionally close a tag
- Nesting two ng-repeats (I have not tried it):

The first ng-repeat will iterate from 0 to Math.round(total/5). You can achieve this by having a range() function on your $rootScope that you can define like the following

```
angular.module('yourApp').run(['$rootScope', function ($rootScope) {
    $rootScope.range = function (start, end) {
        var i,
            range = [];
        for (var i = start; i < end; i += 1) {
            range.push(i);
        }
        return range;
    };
});
```

Then nest an ng-repeat with a slice filter or offset filter

```
angular.module('yourApp').filter('slice', function () {
    return function(array, start, end) {
       return array.slice(start, end);
    }
});

angular.module('yourApp').filter('offset', function () {
    return function(array, from) {
       return array.slice(from);
    }
});
```

And in your partial

```
  <div class="fluid-row" ng-repeat="n in range(0, Math.round(item.length / 5))">
    <div class="click panel col-lg-2" ng-repeat="item in items | offset:$index*5 | limitTo:5">
        <img src="{{item.Image}}" width="150" height="150">
    </div>
  </div>
```